# Where in K-ON! does the second panel of this image of Azusa come from?

Tags: k-on

I know that the image is of Azusa from K-ON, but I don't know where it is from exactly. I don't think it was in the original anime?

I'm referring to [the second panel of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/515Ju.jpg) **[NSFW]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't think this was put in the original anime

lol of course not

It's fanart by an artist named くまもとこ / "kuma motoko" who [used to be on pixiv](http://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=2617199) but has since deleted his/her account. Some remnants of his/her art, not including the Azusa picture (but including a different picture from the same set), can be seen [on Twitpic (NSFW)](http://twitpic.com/photos/metal_motoko).

Comment: And I expected it to be a hentai doujinshi :(. My dreams are crushed.